# Is it possible to use clickhouse to implement efficient union-find algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, filesystems, clickhouse

I have typical union-find problem where I have to group records, but it includes multiple files of hundreds bilion of records.

Can I somehow use clickhouse database to solve it?

Edit - minimal reproducible example:
I have tree columns (item_id, from, to) which represent graph nodes.
I want to create groups (id, group_id, item_id) which names groups from disjoint sets.

[Data]

```
item_id  from  to
0        101   102
1        102   103
2        104   105
```

[Result]

```
id  group_id  item_id
0   0         0
1   0         1
2   1         2
```

There are only two groups #0 (101->102->103) and #1 (104->105).

The problem in implementation in memory is that there's too much records and I want clickhouse (or some other solution) to care about filesystem caches.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]. All code and errors should be in the question as formatted text, not as links or images.

Comment: Can't you implement it by yourself ? Even with the *rank* heuristic and *path compression*, this is not so complicated.

Comment: You probably want to ask about whatever you really want to accomplish, because the best way to do it will probably not involve implementing a union-find data structure in a database.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your specific data and questions, it is tricky to provide a definitive answer. In general, this represents a moderate size for ClickHouse. [UNION](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/union/) is fully supported. Your best bet is to simply try - [loading data](https://clickhouse.com/blog/getting-data-into-clickhouse-part-1) or [generating data](https://clickhouse.com/blog/generating-random-test-distribution-data-for-clickhouse) is straightforward and SQL queries can usually be translated from Postgresql/MySQL easily.

Comment: The question is about the disjoint-set data structure, I guess.

Comment: Makes sense. Probably this is possible to simulate the basic operations with an array type but this might not scale well. Doing it and respecting the spirit of using a tree is challenging without support for recursive CTEs. If you just need to implement the ops it might be simpler.